# Playing music from a link to resourses

Tags: c#, hyperlink

I wanted to make looped background music for my game. I'm working in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. In C# I wrote this:

```
InitializeComponent();
System.Media.SoundPlayer sp = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"MCStratV1.Properties.Resources.loop1.mp3");

//sp.PlayLooping();

sp.Play();
```

And I don't know how to do a link to resources. I'm new at C# so I don't know much about it.
Also I wrote // because I'm not sure it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here.

First, if you look at [the MSDN page for SoundPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Media.SoundPlayer.aspx) you'll find that it says "Controls playback of a sound from a .wav file." So as a start you'll have to convert your mp3 to wav format.

Second, the [constructor that takes a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143771.aspx) wants the path to the wav file on disk, not the path of a resource. You'll either have to give the path to the file, or stream the file and pass the stream to [another form of the constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143770.aspx).